# Continuity of Solution to Bellman Equation in discounting factor $\uparrow 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamic-programming

Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact subset and $C(K)$ the set of real-valued continuous functions on $K$, endowed with the sup norm.

Let $g \in C(K)$ and $f:K \to K$ and 
$T_\beta:C(K)\to C(K)$ be an operator such that
$$(T_\beta F)(x)=\max_{a \in [0,1]} a g(x) + (1-a) \beta F(f(x))$$

Suppose that

(1) for any $[0,1]$ (yes, inclusive), I know that there is a *unique* fixed point $F$ to the functional equation $F=T_\beta F$. Call it $F_\beta$, for $\beta \in [0,1]$.

(2) $\forall \beta \in [0,1)$, $T_\beta$ satisfies Blackwell's conditions for $T_\beta$ to be a contraction. Hence, it has a unique fixed point. Call it $G_\beta$, for $\beta \in [0,1)$.

Question:
For any sequence $(\beta_n)_{n\geq 1}$ where $\beta_n \in [0,1)$ and such that $\beta_n \uparrow 1$, is it the case that $G_{\beta_n} \to F_1$?

Comment: I assume $g$ is not necessarily nonnegative. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $g$ is nonnegative.

Comment: In that case, I have a partial answer for you (posted below). I say partial because I had to make a non-trivial assumption (referred to as (H1) in the post). Let me know if this suffices for you. I don't think the claim is true if I remove (H1), but I haven't thought hard enough about this.

Comment: I was hoping to hear some feedback on my answer and have a fruitful discussion `:-)` I'd like to hear the motivation behind the problem.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Sorry for the lack of details in the statement of the problem. $f$ is indeed continuous, which could've made the solution easier.
In particular, I think this is useful to show that the limiting solution to a contraction mapping as $\beta \to 1$ retains properties showed via the value function belonging to a closed subset of a given functional space. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. What was the motivation behind the problem?

Comment: I was trying to convince myself of a proof that just stated this as a fact along the way

Comment: I was thinking about the proof and if $f$ is continuous and we focus on the set of continuous functions over $K$, it seems like we could get that $T$ as a function of $(F,\beta)$ is continuous. And this would be enough,I suppose.

Comment: If you have time, you should flesh out the details in this alternate solution and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take, without future mention,

- $K$ to be an arbitrary set (not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}^n$),
- $g$ to be a *bounded* and *nonnegative* real-valued map from $K$ (not necessarily continuous),
- $f$ to be a map from $K$ to itself (not necessarily continuous), and
- $(\beta_n)_n$ to be a real sequence converging monotonically from below to one.

In particular, no topological structure is imposed on $K$.

*Remark*.
With regards to your original post, I don't see how $T_{\beta}$ is necessarily a map from $C(K)$ to itself since you impose no continuity on $f$.
Therefore, in stating the main result below, I use the space of bounded real-valued maps $B(K)$.

> **Theorem**. Suppose the following:
>
> (H1) For each $x$, the supremum $\sup_{k\geq0}[g\circ f^{k}](x)$ is attained at a nonnegative integer $k$.
>
> (H2) The operator $T_{\beta}$ defined by $T_{\beta}F\equiv\max_{0 \leq a \leq 1} ag+(1-a)\beta[F\circ f]$ has a unique fixed point in $B(K)$ for each $\beta$ between zero and one (inclusive).
>
> Denote by $F_{\beta}$ the unique fixed point of $T_{\beta}$.
>   Then, $F_{\beta_{n}}\rightarrow F_{1}$ pointwise.

We prove the above in a series of lemmas.

*Conventions*.
We always use $\beta$ to mean a number between zero and one (inclusive).
We take $\inf \emptyset = \infty$.
$\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes the sup-norm.
$f^k$ denotes the composition of $f$ with itself $k$ times.

First, since the maximum of a linear function on an interval is obtained at one of the boundaries,
$$
T_{\beta}F=\max_{0\leq a\leq1}ag+\left(1-a\right)\beta[F\circ f]=\max\left\{ g,\beta[F\circ f]\right\} .
$$
This suggests that the Bellman equation is the dynamic program associated to a deterministic optimal stopping problem in which the state at time $k$ is $X_{k}\equiv f^{k}(x)$.
The controller has to choose a time $k$ to stop at to receive the reward $\beta^{k}g(X_{k})=\beta^{k}[g\circ f^{k}](x)$.
You can think of $(X_k)_k$ as a Markov chain with deterministic transitions.
Unless there is no discount ($\beta=1$), the controller prefers to stop earlier in order to minimize adverse discounting effects.
This is made rigorous below.

**Lemma 1 (Characterizing a fixed point)**. $V_{\beta}\equiv\sup_{k\geq0}\beta^{k}[g\circ f^{k}]$
is a fixed point of $T_{\beta}$.

*Proof*. Substituting $V_{\beta}$ into $T_{\beta}$, 
$$
T_{\beta}V_{\beta}=\max\left\{ g,\sup_{k\geq0}\beta^{k+1}[g\circ f^{k+1}]\right\} =\sup_{k\geq0}\beta^{k}[g\circ f^{k}]
=V_{\beta}.
$$

**Lemma 2 (Properties of $V_{\beta}$)**. $V_{\alpha}\leq V_{\beta}$ whenever $0\leq\alpha\leq\beta$ and $\sup_{\beta}\Vert V_{\beta}\Vert<\infty$.

*Proof*. The first inequality follows immediately from the definition of $V_{\beta}$ in Lemma 1.
As for the second inequality, note that $\beta^{k}\leq1$ and hence $\Vert V_{\beta}\Vert\leq\Vert g\Vert < \infty$.

**Corollary 3 (Convergence)**. The (pointwise) limit $V\equiv\lim_n V_{\beta_{n}}$ exists.

*Proof*. Apply the monotone convergence theorem pointwise to $V_{\beta_{n}}(x)$.

Next, we define the optimal stopping time

$$
k_{\beta}(x)\equiv\inf\left\{ k\geq0\colon V_{\beta}(x)=\beta^{k}[g\circ f^{k}](x)\right\} .
$$
Since $g$ is nonnegative and $\beta<1$, it follows that
$$
0\leq \beta^{k}[g\circ f^{k}](x)\leq\beta^{k}\left\Vert g\right\Vert \rightarrow0\text{ as }k\rightarrow\infty
$$
and hence $k_{\beta}<\infty$.
However, establishing $k_1 < \infty$ requires assuming (H1).

**Lemma 4**. $V\leq V_{1}$.

*Proof*. Let $x$ be arbitrary.
Letting $k_{n}\equiv k_{\beta_{n}}$ for brevity,
\begin{multline*}
V(x)
=\lim_{n}V_{\beta_{n}}(x)
=\lim_{n}\left(\beta_{n}\right)^{k_{n}(x)}[g\circ f^{k_{n}(x)}](x)\\
\leq\lim_{n}[g\circ f^{k_{n}(x)}](x)
\leq\sup_{k\geq0}[g\circ f^{k}](x)
=V_{1}(x).
\end{multline*}

**Lemma 5**. Suppose (H1). Then, $V\geq V_{1}$.

Proof. Let $x$ be arbitrary. Then,
\begin{multline*}
V(x)
=\lim_{n}V_{\beta_{n}}(x)
=\lim_{n}\sup_{k\geq0}\left(\beta_{n}\right)^{k}[g\circ f^{k}](x)\\
\geq\lim_{n}\left(\beta_{n}\right)^{k_{1}(x)}[g\circ f^{k_{1}(x)}](x)
=[g\circ f^{k_{1}(x)}](x)
=V_{1}(x).
\end{multline*}

We are now ready to prove the theorem.

*Proof of the Theorem*. Since fixed points are unique by assumption (H2), $V_{\beta}=F_{\beta}$, and the result follows from combining Lemmas 4 and 5.

It is worthwhile, as a closing note, to discuss assumption (H1).
Intuitively, (H1) tells us that the controller can always choose a finite optimal stopping time (this does not preclude the existence of infinite optimal stopping times).
There are some interesting cases that trivially satisfy (H1), such as (*i*) $K$ being a finite set or (*ii*) the image of $K$ under $g$ being a finite set.